# Post XML file to web service without using service reference

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services, post, soap

I am trying to debug some vb code that is experiencing issues with one of our web services. I am trying to submit an XML file with vb .net to mimic the VB code as much as possible since I do not have a non .Net VB IDE. I do not experience the issue when using web references in a project.

Here is the VB code I am trying to emulate in VB .Net

```
Dim oHttp As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Set oHttp = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest


Call oHttp.Open("POST", m_URL, False)
oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", " text/xml"
Call oHttp.send(request)
Call oHttp.waitForResponse
'Process response
Dim response As String
response = oHttp.responseText
Set oHttp = Nothing
```

Here is my code so far:

```
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/service/service.asmx")
    Dim xml As String = String.Empty
    Dim sr As New StreamReader("c:\xmlfile.xml")
    xml = sr.ReadToEnd
    sr.Close()
    sr.Dispose()

    Dim bytesToWrite As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml)

    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentLength = bytesToWrite.Length
    request.ContentType = "text/xml"
    request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "[web service url]/Submit")

    Dim newStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    newStream.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length)
    newStream.Close()

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)

    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

My web service is receiving the request but the object is null

Comment: Do you want to use the same WinHttpRequest class?  You can either use the same COM library, or you can rewrite the code to use the new .NET equivalents.

Comment: @SteveDog .Net equivalents would be fine, I have updated my question with what I have so far.

Comment: What object is null?  In the web service it receives a null object, or on the client it receives a null object back from the web service?

Comment: @SteveDog the XML object in the request is null on the service side. I followed instructions at the link below to capture the request and the file does indeed contain the xml request I sent. It is like it is not getting serialized properly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension(VS.80).aspx#Y0